# Why won't my alphaNumeric validation rules work in my CakePHP model?

Tags: php, cakephp

I have tried this below validations for my fields.

My fields are Title, Content.

```
var $validate = array('title' =>array('alphaNumeric'=>array('rule'=>'alphaNumeric','required'=>'true','message'=>'Enter a title for this post',)),
                     'content'=>array('alphaNumeric'=>array('rule'=>'alphaNumeric','required'=>'true','message'=>'Enter some content for this post',)));
```

But whenever i enter some text in my form and try to submit, it shows error message...

Is there any problem with the validations ?

Here's my form

```
<h2> Add a Post Here </h2>
Please fill in all the fields.
<?php
echo $this->form->create('Post');
echo $this->form->error('Post.title');
echo $this->form- >input('Post.title',array('id'=>'posttitle','label'=>'title','size'=>'50','maxlength'=>'255','error'=>false));
echo $this->form->error('Post.content');
echo $this->form->input('Post.content',array('id'=>'postcontent','type'=>'textarea','label'=>'Content:','rows'=>'10','error'=>false));
echo $this->form->end(array('label'=>'Submit Post'));
?>
```

Comment: can you post the the form in your question

Comment: What if you write $this->form- >input('title'..)   in place of $this->form- >input('Post.title',..)?

Comment: Does it give errors even if you enter something without space?

Comment: Oops i got it....i was using ','.

Comment: Now how to allow, spaces and other characters in the above fields???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use custom regular expression.

```
'rule'    => array('custom', '[a-zA-Z0-9, ]+'),
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the regular expression as follows to get it to work.

```
        'alphaNumeric' => array(
            'rule' => array('custom', '/[a-zA-Z0-9, ]+/'),
            'message' => 'Only letters and numbers allowed',
```

Why won't the built in alphaNumeric rule do this already?